# I need to create a listView like a comment list in my app

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an `Activity`  that has 2 `Fragments` when I call the activity it create the `Fragments` and its information from `Fragment A`, but in the `Fragment B` I have a `ListView` (**Comments ListView**) but it doesn't appear when I change from `Fragment A` to `Fragment B`.

The `ListView` only appears if i click on `add comment button`. The `ListView` only appears when i press a `Button` of that `Fragment`. I don't know how to run the **`ResponseListener`** or **`Volley`**.

**This is my code:**

```
public class NegocioCommentFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView listView;
    private FloatingActionButton crearComentario;
    private String neg_Nombre;
    final List<HashMap<String, String>> mapFill = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private String neg_id;


    public NegocioCommentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_negocio_comments, container, false);


    }


    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        crearComentario = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.agregarComentario);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentsList);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String usrapp_id = sharedPreferences.getString("usrapp_id", null);


        //Accedemos a los extras para ectraer nombre e id del negocio
        Intent negocioInfo = getActivity().getIntent();
        final Bundle paqueteInfo = negocioInfo.getExtras();
        neg_Nombre = paqueteInfo.getString("neg_Nombre");
        neg_id = paqueteInfo.getString("neg_id");


        crearComentario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent enviarComentarioActivity = new Intent(getContext(), EnviarComentario.class);
                enviarComentarioActivity.putExtra("neg_Nombre", neg_Nombre);
                enviarComentarioActivity.putExtra("usrapp_id", usrapp_id);
                enviarComentarioActivity.putExtra("neg_id", neg_id);
                startActivity(enviarComentarioActivity);

                //Creamos arreglos para el adaptador de los comentarios
                String[] negInfo = new String[]{"nombre", "nc_comentario",};
                int[] views = new int[]{R.id.userNameCommentTextView, R.id.userCommentTextView};


                //LLenamos los componentes de la lista de comentarios con los arreglos en donde se guardaron
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), mapFill, R.layout.diseno_negocio_comments, negInfo, views);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

        //Traemos todos los comentarios del que se han hecho últimamente al negocio
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray comentariosArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < comentariosArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject comentarioJson = comentariosArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String nombre = comentarioJson.getString("nombre");
                        String comentario = comentarioJson.getString("nc_comentario");
                        String fechaComentario = comentarioJson.getString("nc_fecha");
                        String calificacion = comentarioJson.getString("calificacion");

                        HashMap<String, String> commentsInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        commentsInfo.put("nombre", nombre);
                        commentsInfo.put("nc_comentario", comentario);
                        commentsInfo.put("fechaComentario", fechaComentario);
                        commentsInfo.put("calificacion", calificacion);
                        mapFill.add(commentsInfo);

                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        TraeComentariosRequest traeComentariosRequest = new TraeComentariosRequest(neg_id, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        queue.add(traeComentariosRequest);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }


}
```